# Wait for GPS Location fix before sending message

Tags: android, gps

How do I wait for an actual GPS location before sending an SMS? Directly using requestLocationUpdates sends me a message that returns 0.0 as latitude and longitude but the GPS hasn't been able to get the correct coordinates yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use requestLocationUpdates with the GPS provider and give proper receiver.

```
requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, myReceiver);
```

Then in onLocationChanged method defined in your receiver check for provider to be GPS and also for the time of update.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Check the time of update to be fairly recent, this should give you proper GPS coords.

Comment: When exactly does onLocationChanged get fired? If for example a person has already gotten an initial coordinate and suddenly moves to another place, will it be fired before or after the satellite acquires the latest coordinates?

Comment: onLocationChanged gets fired based on the minTime (second parameter) and minDistance (third parameter) of the requestLocationUpdates method. However since we put but as 0, it would keep the GPS running and relay all the location information it gets. So as you move and if the phone is in line of sight of the satellites you would keep getting the location updates instantly.

Comment: You can also use the accuracy field (less than 10m) in case you need more accurate information to weed out all the data received while GPS is still trying to get the most accurate fix.

Comment: But how do I know that it has already retrieved the coordinates for that particular area? I think I should be continually firing requestLocationUpdate to see if it has already received new coordinates, although I think using a while loop would be a stupid thing to do.

Comment: You dont need any while loop once you do a requestLocationUpdate it will relay all the datapoints it is getting. For your question regarding coords of that area. Use the accuracy field for less than 10-25m it is fairly reliable. You need to fire requestLocationUpdate just once and it registers callback and will keep on relaying the data until you call removeUpdates().

Comment: Will the LocationListener also be running in the background and fire onLocationChanged whenever it receives new coordinates?

Comment: Yes given that you have not killed the context.

Comment: How can I access the new coordinates returned by the listener outside the class itself? I don't think I should be using static.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.Listener.html) may be of help, in conjunction with [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.html)

Comment: How should I go about implementing this? I'm using a LocationListener and a LocationManager atm.

Comment: Create a new GpsStatusListener. Implement onGpsStatusChanged() for GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX, and you will know when a GPS fix has been made. Of course, if GPS was already enabled and had a fix before your application started, you would need some additional code to handle that situation as well.

Comment: Are the events for getting the first fix and the succeeding fixes different? I was hoping to use removeUpdates after receiving a fix to save on battery life.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways. It depends on your use case, which is more suitable for you.

1. I personally use [LocationManager#requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29). A callback in my activity is invoked then.
2. However it may take a while to receive the most recent location. If an immediate location is required, you can use the [getLastKnownLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Comment: I am also using requestLocationUpdate, however, it doesn't wait for the most recent location and fires back the initial value, which is 0.0.

Comment: @louieansonng requestLocationUpdate returning 0, 0 could be a bug specific to your phone model, or are you using the emulator?

Comment: I am currently using an LG Optimus p500 as a test device